# jQuery edit attribute values with [i]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI Sortable for Drag/Drop re-ordering of rows in a table, and it's working fine.

However, the inputs in the rows have a counter which is their position in the table.
They are of the format:

```
td
    input(class="form-control itemDesc" type="text" name="items[0][desc]")
    input(class="form-control rowQty" type="number" step="any" name="items[0][qty]" value="1")
etc..
```

I cannot change the formatting of this.

I will be passing a callback function to be run on the completion of the drag/drop, which checks the new position of the row in the table, and that will be my value to use to replace the [i].

How would I manipulate the number between the square brackets? How would I perform the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'replace the [i]' you are referring to the index value inside the name attribute then it's just simple string manipulation.

This will work.

```
$('td input').each(function(index, element) {
    var name = element.getAttribute('name');
    element.setAttribute('name', name.slice(0, name.indexOf('[') + 1) + newIndexValue + name.slice(name.indexOf(']'), name.length));
});
```